# GIS services on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gis, geography

There is any geocoding/routing service which runs on Google App Engine? (besides the Google Maps API)

Comment: can you please provide more detail as to what exactly you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine doesn't have built-in geocoding or routing, so you're left with two options: Load map data into App Engine and geocode/route locally, or call out to a web service.

The former isn't a particularly good use of App Engine (or particularly practical). The latter works just fine - but means that the selection of GIS services available is exactly the same for App Engine as it is for every other platform. You mention one yourself - the Google Maps API.

Comment: I would like to know more about ther first option.  Do you know any GIS project that uses the DataStore provided by Google?  I am only able to find projects using a relational database (Postgres + PostGIS and the like).

Answer (score 1):

If you search how to find a user location you can look here:
http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2008/08/where-is-my-current-user.html

You can  create dynamically user id, put it into ajax variable and send id back to server with geolocation described in link above.